# Redirect the entire page from MVC3 Razor iFrame page to a different URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an razor page **https://myDomain1.com/myFrame.cshtml**  with a "continue" button on it

this razor page is an iframe inside another **parent.cshtml**

When I click on the "Continue" button I want to redirect my entire page(including parent page) to https://myDomain2.com/default .

Given below is the ActionResult  in my Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult myFrame(TestViewModel model)
    {

      Response.Redirect("https://myDomain2.com/default");

       return View(model);
    }
```

with my above code only the iframe part of the page is redirecting but my requirement is to redirect the entire page to **https://myDomain2.com/default**
My problem here is that ,I want to redirect my entire page(including parent page) to **https://myDomain2.com/default** .

**Please help me how to redirect the entire page to a different domain URL**

Answer (score 7):

In the case that you must use this solution (sticking with frames), simply include the javascript content result - something along these lines:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult myFrame(TestViewModel model)
    {
       return Content("<html><script>window.top.location.href = "http://www.whatever.com"; </script></html>");
    }
```

Your frames must be in the same domain though for this to work.

Answer (score 6):

HTTP does not allow you to specify the target frame in the response.

Instead, set `target="_top"` in the original `<form>`, or put a Javascript frame-buster in the target page.

Comment: Or, better yet, stop using frames.

Comment: SLaks -- sometimes there are legacy systems that we must handle.