# Unable to redirect to an external website from an iframe using Asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, iframe, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 3 different websites A, B, C. The iframe is on website A and points to website B.

A - a django website 
B and C- asp.net mvc websites

The redirect occurs on B when you click a button(submit), it performs an operation and then redirect to C, but unfortunately the redirect occurs inside the iframe. I want to redirect completely.

I tried return `RedirectPermanent(url)` inside my MVC Controller `Redirect(url)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.sitec.com";
```

Keep in mind the site you are redirecting to must abide by the "same origin policy" in order to work. [same origin policy](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy)

Comment: The redirect needs to be performed from the controller, not from javascript.

Comment: Ok perhaps this previous question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236016/redirect-the-entire-page-from-mvc3-razor-iframe-page-to-a-different-url

Comment: @Zinov You must understand that the controller, or the whole server-side for that matter, has no idea that it is running in an iframe. You cannot force a client to do something if you aren't the client. Simple as that.